# Declare Map fields with type system

Tags: java

In Java say I have a class that represents http headers:

```
 public class Headers {
       String 'x-requested-by' = "foo";
       String 'content-type' = "application/json"
 }
```

because of the field names with non-standard variable names (hyphens), typically a more dynamic map is used like so:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

but my quesetion is - is there a way to declare which fields will exist in there statically, instead of only at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an enum map, which will only accept keys of a specified enum type, while the enum itself will statically limit options.

```
enum Headers {
    X_REQUESTED_BY("x-requested-by"), CONTENT_TYPE("content-type");

    private String headerName;

    private Headers(String n) {
        this.headerName = n;
    }

    public String getHeaderName() {
        return headerName;
    }
}
```

And use the enum map to store values:

```
Map<Headers, String> headerValues = new EnumMap<>(Headers.class);
```

Your API can then be extended with such methods as `addHeader(Headers h)`, which makes it possible to statically limit options while keeping it type-safe.

Answer (score 1):

No. Only one thing you can do is init a `Map` with default values after initialization.

```
public class Header {
     public static final String X_REQUESTED_BY = "x-requested-by";
     public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "content-type";

     private final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

     {
         map.put(X_REQUESTED_BY, "foo");
         map.put(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
     }
 }
```